# Pass in variable to dockerized php application in Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: php, docker, aws-cli

I am in a specific situation where I am deploying a dockerized PHP application to AWS Fargate using Bitbucket pipelines. I am trying to pass in a variable that contains sensitive info to the PHP application. The sensitive info I have stored as a parameter in Parameter Store. My idea is to pass in the value of this parameter into the PHP application by making an aws cli call to retrieve the value. Then, I created a variable within my PHP script to call the AWS CLI command. However after I deploy, the value is not showing. Below is the code and output. Any advice would be helpful.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY index.php index.php
EXPOSE 80
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$secretValue=`aws ssm get-parameter --name secretValue --with-decryption | jq '.Parameter.Value'`;
echo "Hello World!";
echo "Secret is $secretValue";
?>
```

**Current Output**

```
Hello World!Secret is
```

**Desired Output**

```
Hello World!Secret is {value_from_aws_cli_call}
```

Comment: `docker run -e MY_SUPER_SECRET=foo`, or `--env-file`, or `-v`. See `man docker-run`.

Answer (score 0):

The CLI looks good to me, maybe jq needs to have -r to output raw strings, not JSON texts;

have a try: aws ssm get-parameter --name secretValue --with-decryption | jq **-r** '.Parameter.Value'` ?